# How to display streaming video receive from surveillance camera system on website

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, video-streaming

I want to display streaming video from surveillance camera system on website (asp.net/html5). From their api document, I can get snapshot to show on img tag but I can't get streaming media (H.264) to show on video tag.

I've try to open it with VLC player but I can't get it to work.
I don't know if it's because it has response contentType multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--DigifortBoundary; that make video tag won't work.

I've try on video tag like this.

```
<video id="video1" controls autoplay
  src="http://localhost:8601/Interface/Cameras/GetMediaStream?Camera=01&AuthUser=admin&AuthPass=password" >
</video>
```

Comment: Sounds like MJPEG to me, not H.264.  Can you confirm that, and confirm the stream format?

Comment: I don't know how to confirm but I believe it is H.264 because camera profile on server was set that way and camera it self also set to H.264.

Comment: I found out more about response `-DigifortBoundary
Content-Type: video/h264
Content-Length: 117640
DGF-FrameType: h.264/I-Frame`

Answer (score 1):

I am working on the same issue with Digifort HTTP API. Current workaround for me is by requesting MJPEG live video stream instead.

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none; max-width: 100%;" src="http://192.168.0.38:8601/Interface/Cameras/GetJPEGStream?Camera=02&ResponseFormat=XML&Quality=100&Width=1920&Height=1080&AuthUser=admin&AuthPass=123456">
```

Note that MJPEG uses `<img>` element and it is not natively supported in IE.

Comment: Yeah, I have to do that too. I try to avoid use that API because document said it would overload server but it seem I don't have a choice right now. Do you perhaps also know how to export video file from Digifort?

Comment: To export video you can refer the documentation provided by Digifort at section '4.3.9.5 Exporting'

Comment: Which API version you use? Mine is version 1.7.0 for Digifort 7.2.0.0

Comment: download this version https://drive.google.com/open?id=13jtli3pVONFaYIZmAB8AReaOxnAUjRhN

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an elementary H.264 stream, and I'm guessing based on those headers that it just contains I-frames.  Because it's an elementary stream, it isn't something you can just play back in a `<video>` tag.  You need to mux it with a container first, such as MP4.  Then, you need to get that data into the video element.

First, you need to get that stream with the Fetch API.  Ensure that even works on your origin and that there are not any CORS issues.

Next, you'll need to figure out how to mux that stream.  There are a handful of JavaScript libraries for this, but I cannot offer a specific suggestion as I haven't tested any.  (Maybe https://github.com/videojs/mux.js/?  Not sure if that works client-side or not.)

Once you have your MP4 stream, you'll need to use [Media Source Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API) to get that content into something playable.

There is an alternative to all this.  Mux it server-side with FFmpeg.